# Hide Child Objects Together with the Parent

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've got a little problem. On a button press I need to open a panel with settings in animation. The thing is when I reduce width and height of a parent object (panel) it does not hide the child objects whatsoever. How can I make the parent object to influence the children's height and width when I change them in the parent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If these objects are UI elements you can use add a [Mask](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-Mask.html) to the panel to hide any child objects that go outside of the area of the panel. As you can see below the square which is a child of the panel object does not render anything outside of the area of the panel.

[image]

If you want the UI elements to scale with the changing size of the panel then you should use [anchors](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UIBasicLayout.html) which will mean that the children of the panel will "anchor" themselves to the positions you set. Here's a short gif to illustrate how it works.

[image]

That's with the child image set to preserve it's aspect ratio, if you disable that setting then the box will stretch to perfectly fit the anchors.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to scale your child objects with your parent canvas, you should set your render mode -> world space in your parent object.